# Unknown Server tag only in published ASP.Net Web site

Tags: asp.net, peterblum

I am seeing a strange problem with an ASP.Net website after it has been published and deployed to a remote host. I did read through a lot of posts on unknown server tag, but all of them had this error in the dev environment unlike in my case.

It gives the following ASP.Net error in deployed website, but never in the same website running on my local machine.

`Unknown Server Tag 'drg:GridEditCommandColumn'`

The unknown server tag is for a PeterBlum GridEditCommandColumn type, which is defined in a code file under App_Code folder. Since the unknown tag type is defined under App_Code folder, it makes it very confusing as to why its not being registered in published version only.

The user control in which the `dr:GridEditCommandColumn` is used already has a valid registration of this tag.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="drg" Namespace="PeterBlum.DES.TelerikWebUI" %>
```

**Question**  Why would I get this error only in published version and never in local dev version? All other pages in deployed website project work fine except for this page, even though all dll files and the page files have been deployed correctly.

[image: Unknown Server Tag]

**UPDATE 1**

It appears to be something wrong with my hosting provider. My published files are perfect, since when I deploy the same set of files to another hosting provider it works with no problems.  I am now waiting for the first hosting  provider to get back. It may be some settings that the first hosting provider may have applied that is causing this and App_Code.dll to be not picked up.

**UPDATE 2**

I was able to finally solve this issue. It was not anything on the hosting provider's end, but on my end. I added an 'Assembly' attribute to the Register directive in user control as suggested by Wiktor Zychla in one of the comments and also, removed the original Register directive from the parent page.

The original Register directive in parent page was without the Assembly attribute. Still, I am confused why the original Register directive worked perfectly on Microsoft's Azure servers but failed on another third-party hosting servers.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="drg" Namespace="PeterBlum.DES.TelerikWebUI"  Assembly="App_Code"%>
```

Comment: Just making sure, but the root directory for the app is marked as an application correct? Otherwise your App_Code directory wouldn't be picked up since it's not under the correct root.

Comment: You mean an application IIS?

Comment: I do get App_Code.dll file created after publishing. And when I look the published App_Code.dll file in 'Object Browser' in VS 2013, then I do see that type which is throwing unknown server tag error.

Comment: Seems you miss the assembly attribute in your register directive. The attribute should point to the assembly the component is defined. Also make sure the assembly is copied together with the app.

Comment: I have the type defined in the same website under App_Code folder, so I excluded the assembly name.

Comment: It seems its something to do with my hosting provider settings.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, Can you post your comment as an answer, since that helped me solve my problem?

Comment: Just post your findings as your own answer. Sounds like my comment only directed you to a final solution.